# PDFBox getNumberOfPages() on Aspose generated doc returns 0

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, aspose

I'm using PDFBox and for some reason when getting the number of pages on a document that was generated with Aspose (aspose.pdf-17.4) PDFBox (2.0.4) returns 0 pages, does anybody know a workaround for it? I tried loading the document and resaving with PDFBox but it didn't seem to work :S

The code is very simple:

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
doc.load(new File (file_path));
int p = dac.getNumberOfPages();
doc.close();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share a pdf for which you observe the issue.

Comment: And please update to PDFBox 2.0.8. And be aware that load() is a static call, so no need to construct a PDDocument object.

Comment: The issue got resolved after updating the Aspose and PDFBox libraries, thanks

Comment: Consider deleting the question or answering it yourself. Using the latest software is best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct number of pages after updating with aspose.pdf-17.8 and PDFBox 2.0.8, thanks to Tilman Hausherr for pointing the version.

Comment: 2.0.8 is current, not 2.0.7.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not share an example document. With it we could have determined whether it's an aspose or a pdfbox issue.